# MongoDB. Configuration and local backup fail

Tags: mongodb

I have the root user created with the roles root and backup.

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.root",
        "userId" : UUID("75a17c1d-f5d5-4c4b-85f6-0992f2e80c29"),
        "user" : "root",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "backup",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

According to this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251703/mongo-mongodump-and-the-config-database-error
, having the backup role is enough to be able to make backup copies of admin, config and local, but:

With the admin database I have no problems, but with local and config.

```
mongodump mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/config
2021-09-17T11:29:19.470+0200    WARNING: On some systems, a password provided directly in a connection string or using --uri may be visible to system status programs such as `ps` that may be invoked by other users. Consider omitting the password to provide it via stdin, or using the --config option to specify a configuration file with the password.
2021-09-17T11:29:19.477+0200    Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

If I try to login to the database config

```
/home/mongo/mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017 -u root -p ***** -authenticationDatabase config
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/test?authSource=config&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

If I try to create the root user for the config database

```
> use config
switched to db config
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "root",
...     pwd: "****",
...     roles: [ "root" ]
...   }
... )
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: No role named root@config :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1343:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Do you know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Try including `authSource` in the [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).